# Need to ignore empty EditText when saving to parse.com

Tags: java, android, android-activity, parse-platform

So I've been doing pretty well so far until I have to save the text to parse.com. The code will not ignore the empty EditText fields which I think is causing the error. I have tried to use setText ("") so it will save empty but it still creates an error. Does anybody know of a way to ignore the empty EditText fields?

Here is my code below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.edit_profile);



    psnEditText1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.psnEditText);

    xboxEditText2 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.xboxEditText);
    lolEditText3 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.lolEditText);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
    query.whereEqualTo("username", UserId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject> () {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject thisUser : objects){
                    //access the data associated with the ParseUser using the get method
                    //pu.getString("key") or pu.get("key")
                    //UNAME = thisUser.getUsername();
                    PlayStationId = thisUser.getString("PlayStation ID");
                    XboxLiveID = thisUser.getString("Xbox Live ID");
                    LeagueofLegendsId = thisUser.getString ("League of Legends ID");
                    oid = thisUser.getObjectId();
                }


                psnEditText1.setText (PlayStationId);
                xboxEditText2.setText(XboxLiveID);
                lolEditText3.setText (LeagueofLegendsId);


            } else {
                Log.d ("query", "Error: " + e.getMessage ());
            }
        }
    });




    saveButton = (Button) findViewById (R.id.saveButton);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            if (currentUser != null) {

                final String psnID = psnEditText1.getText().toString();
                final String xboxID = xboxEditText2.getText().toString();
                final String lolID = lolEditText3.getText().toString();

                UserId = currentUser.getObjectId ();

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery ("User");
                query.whereEqualTo("username", UserId);
                // Retrieve the object by id
                query.getInBackground (oid, new GetCallback<ParseObject> () {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseObject UserDataUpdate, ParseException e) {

                       // if (psnID.isEmpty () || xboxID.isEmpty () ||
                                //lolID.isEmpty ()) {

                           // psnEditText1.setText ("Not Available", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                           // xboxEditText2.setText ("Not Available", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
                            //lolEditText3.setText ("Not Available", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);


                           // Toast.makeText (EditProfileActivity.this,
                                    //"Be sure all fields are checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();



                       // } else {


                            //Add on extra information to current user then save to parse.com



                                if (psnID.matches ("")){
                                    psnEditText1.setText ("No information entered");


                                    Toast.makeText (EditProfileActivity.this,
                                            "PlayStation ID is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                } else {
                                    UserDataUpdate.put ("PlayStation ID", psnID);

                                }


                                 if (xboxID.matches ("")) {
                                     xboxEditText2.setText ("No information entered");

                                     Toast.makeText (EditProfileActivity.this,
                                             "Xbox Live ID is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                 } else {
                                     UserDataUpdate.put ("Xbox Live ID", xboxID);
                                 }


                                if (lolID.matches ("")) {
                                    lolEditText3.setText ("No information entered");

                                    Toast.makeText (EditProfileActivity.this,
                                            "League of Legends ID is empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                                } else {
                                    UserDataUpdate.put ("League of Legends ID", lolID);
                                }


                            UserDataUpdate.saveInBackground (new SaveCallback () {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText (EditProfileActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();

                                    Intent intent = new Intent (EditProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity (intent);
                                }
                            });

                        }

                });


            }
          }

        });
```

Here is the error that is being thrown: (this occurred after I changed the matches ("") to equals (""))

01-02 16:20:46.537  31994-31994/com.ionictech.gamerzio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at     com.ionictech.gamerzio.UI.EditProfileActivity$2$1.done(EditProfileActivity.java:141)
            at com.parse.GetCallback.internalDone(GetCallback.java:43)
            at com.parse.GetCallback.internalDone(GetCallback.java:29)
            at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:975)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: where is EditProfileActivity.java:141 ? in your code?

Comment: it is this line UserDataUpdate.put ("Xbox Live ID", xboxID);

Comment: Did you validate that UserDataUpdate is not null in this private function? because it could be.

Comment: I didn't validate it but from my attempts is stated that UserDataUpdate is always null.

Comment: So that would be the root of your exception.

Comment: so how do I get it from not always being null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that UserUpdateData is always null, one main problem here is that you aren't actually querying users. To query users, your line

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
```

Should say

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

This is how Parse saves the default user object. Unless you have a custom class titled "User", this will make your query always return null objects. You can see more about this here: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying

Also, according to the Parse guide, the lines

```
query.getInBackground (oid, new GetCallback<ParseObject> () {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseObject UserDataUpdate, ParseException e)
```

Should be

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
  public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `equals`

```
    if (psnID.equals("")) {

          }
```

Because

```
"hello".equals(".*e.*"); // false
"hello".matches(".*e.*"); // true
```

Comment: by looking at the stacktrace you can clearly see this is not part of the problem.

Comment: @cbrulak OP has not added any exceptions previously... He said He is unable to validate empty edittexts. My answer Suits him.... Why dont you answer his question...?